# Статический класс для работы с окнами

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

Есть такой класс в файле offers.h:

```
class Offers {
public:
static void Main ();
static Window *window;
};

void Offers::Main () {
Offers::window = new Window(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL, "WAMS v0.0.2 [Управление товарами]", 
"icons/logo/logo-128x128.png",800,500,15,true);
Offers::window->Show();
}
```

Сразу говорю тип **Window** это класс для удобной работы с окнами. В функции *int main ()* вызывается void OffersMain (*) которая находится в отдельном cpp файле. Содержимое файла offers.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "offers.h"

Offers m;

void OffersMain (GtkWidget *w, gpointer g) {
    m.Main();
}
```

При компиляции получаю такой ответ:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQvYDwC.o: в функции «Offers::Main()»:
offers.cpp:(.text+0xa5): неопределённая ссылка на «Offers::window»
/usr/bin/ld: offers.cpp:(.text+0xdc): неопределённая ссылка на «Offers::window»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Что я делаю не так?!?

Comment: в `offers.cpp` вне функций добавить `Window * Offers::window = nullptr;`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 5):

Самый лучший вариант решения - использовать `C++17`, там добавили одну долгожданную возможность. А именно:

`static inline Window *window = nullptr;`

Ну а если стандарт ниже 17 - то:

```
class Offers {
public:
static void Main ();
static Window *window;
};
Window* Offers::window = nullptr;
```

Comment: А что такое nullptr?

Comment: Да стандарт C++ 11