# Undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'

Tags: c++, windows, curl, undefined-reference

Я пытаюсь подключить libcurl к моему проекту, но на мой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init ();

    return 0;
}
```

я получаю ошибку компилятора `C:\Users\Cubatomic\Desktop\cpp\cpp_11\libcurl_test\main.cpp|10|undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'|`.

В настройках компоновщика я прописал: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.72.0\lib\libcurl.a` и `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.72.0\lib\libcurl.dll.a`

Также в каталогах поиска прописано
для компилятора: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.72.0\include`
для компоновщика: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.72.0\lib`

Также в #defines я добавил  `CURL_STATICLIB`.

Изображения:
[image: Настройки компоновщика, код и ошибка]
[image: Каталоги поиска]

P.S.: Я просмотрел множество форумов и постов, но практически все твердили, что ошибка в подключении .a файлов. libcurl скачивал отсюда: https://curl.haxx.se/windows/. Операционная система Windows 7 x64. Пожалуйста, помогите мне.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема была в том, что компилятор mingw, устанавливаемый в комплекте с Code::Blocks, 32-разрядный, а curllib я скачал для 64-разрядного.

Answer (score 2):

Разместите модули cURL так, чтобы не было пробелов в пути к его файлам. Возможно, проблема в этом.

Также добавьте в проект зависимости:
libcurl_a.lib,
Ws2_32.lib,
Crypt32.lib,
Wldap32.lib,
Normaliz.lib

Comment: Я попробовал, с пробелами проблем нет. А вот с зависимостями появились. Не подскажете пожалуйста, как мне их добавить? Скачать .lib файлы и поместить в папку с проектом? Или же .dll?