# Почему компилятор выдаёт ощибку, при компиляций C++ кода?

Tags: c++, компиляция, makefile, library

Захотел создать shared библиотеку, сама библиотека компилируеться без ощибок.
Создал class, под названием "vector2", с использованием template< typename T >, тут тоже без ощибок компилируеться библиотека.

vector2.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
class vector2
{
public:
    vector2();
    vector2(T x, T y);

    T x = 0, y = 0;
};
```

vector2.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
vector2<T>::vector2() {}

template <typename T>
vector2<T>::vector2(T x, T Y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <AceEngine/AceEngine.hpp>

vector2<float> vec;

int main()
{
    
}
```

Команда компиляций файла main.cpp:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lAceEngine
```

Ощибка компиляций:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccj5Nupg.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `ACE::vector2<float>::vector2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

MakeFile, для компиляций библиотеки:

```
CXX = g++
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC

LIBS = -lSDL2 \
       -lSDL2_image \
       -lSDL2_ttf \
       -lSDL2_mixer \
       -lGL

SOURCE_FILES = source_files/*.cpp
HEADER_FILES = header_files/*.hpp

O_FILES = *.o
LIB = libAceEngine.so

LIB_PATH = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ENGINE_PATH = /usr/include/AceEngine

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c -fPIC $(SOURCE_FILES) $(LIBS)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -shared $(O_FILES) -o $(LIB)
    make -f MakeFile clean

install:
    mkdir $(ENGINE_PATH)
    mv $(LIB) $(LIB_PATH)
    cp -r $(HEADER_FILES) $(ENGINE_PATH)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

uninstall:
    sudo rm -rf $(LIB_PATH)/$(LIB) $(ENGINE_PATH)
```

Как исправить эту ощибку?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: А откуда возьмётся специализация float? Её нужно либо явно объявить, либо отказываться от раздельной компиляции.

Comment: Почему реализация шаблонов в `.cpp` файле?

Comment: С помощью реализаций шаблонов в ` .cpp ` файле, Я смогу скрыть часть кода от людей ну или что-то типо того... .

Comment: Но так делать нельзя. Шаблоны ведь не компилируются. Смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: А есть альтернатива к template?

Comment: В библиотеке будет находиться только откомплированый код. Так как шаблоны компилируются индивидуального для каждого случая, они должны находится в хедерах.

Comment: Мда... Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вам нужно скомпилировать ве реализации шаблонов и положить их в библиотеку

Comment: Что за "ве"? @avp

Comment: Это «все»......

Comment: Можно же просто задекларировать какие специализации шаблона нужны в библиотеке. Так делать можно.

Comment: Что обозначает задекларировать? : D

Comment: `class vector2<float>;`

Comment: Но я хочу чтобы изпользовался class ко всем типам: int, float, double...

Comment: Тогда извините, вам второй вариант из первого комментария)

Comment: Где-то должен лежать объектный код специализации шаблона для нужного типа. В библиотеке - перечисляйте декларации, там где используется - переносите реализацию в заголовок.