# SDL в Visual C++: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, sdl2

Все библиотеки SDL подключены и работают, сделать обычное окно получается, но как только беру пример чуть сложнее все летит. Пишет что идут ссылки на неразрешенные внешние символы.

OS - Windows.

Все  .lib   файлы которые были подключил к проекту, скачивал с офф сайта SDL.

---

**При запуске программы выдаются ошибки:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Программа должна рисовать куб.

**код:**

```
#include <SDL.h> // Библиотека SDL 2
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h> // Библиотека OpenGL
#include <GL/glu.h> // Библиотека GLU

#include <iostream> // стандартная библиотека ввода-вывода в C++
using namespace std;

SDL_Window* window; // задаем окно для SDL

const int width = 640; // ширина окна
const int height = 480; // высота окна

void drawCube(float xrf, float yrf, float zrf);
void init() {

    // Инициализация SDL

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "Unable to init SDL, error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Включаем двойной буфер, настраиваем цвета

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 6);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);

    // Создаем окно с заголовком "Cube", размером 640х480 и расположенным по центру экрана.

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cube", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window); // создаем контекст OpenGL

    if (window == NULL) {   // если не получилось создать окно, то выходим
        exit(1);
    }

    // Инициализация OpenGL

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // устанавливаем фоновый цвет на черный
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // включаем тест глубины
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f); // настраиваем трехмерную перспективу
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // переходим в трехмерный режим
}

void drawCube(float xrf, float yrf, float zrf) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);    // Сдвинуть вглубь экрана

    glRotatef(xrf, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   // Вращение куба по X, Y, Z
    glRotatef(yrf, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   // Вращение куба по X, Y, Z
    glRotatef(zrf, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   // Вращение куба по X, Y, Z

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);      // Рисуем куб

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        // Синяя сторона (Верхняя)
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);      // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);     // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);       // Нижний правый

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);        // Оранжевая сторона (Нижняя)
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Нижний правый

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        // Красная сторона (Передняя)
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);       // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);     // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);      // Нижний правый

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);            // Желтая сторона (Задняя)
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Нижний правый

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Синяя сторона (Левая)
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Нижний правый

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Фиолетовая сторона (Правая)
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Верхний правый угол квадрата
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // Верхний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Нижний левый
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Нижний правый

    glEnd();    // Закончили квадраты

}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    init(); // инициализация

    bool running = true;

    float xrf = 0, yrf = 0, zrf = 0; // углы поворота

    while (running) {

        SDL_Event event; // события SDL

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { // начинаем обработку событий
            switch (event.type) { // смотрим:
            case SDL_QUIT: // если произошло событие закрытия окна, то завершаем работу программы
                running = false;
                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN: // если нажата клавиша
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) { // смотрим какая
                case SDLK_ESCAPE: // клавиша ESC
                    running = false; // завершаем работу программы
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // пока программа запущена изменяем углы поворота, тем самым вращая куб

        xrf -= 0.5;
        yrf -= 0.5;
        zrf -= 0.5;

        drawCube(xrf, yrf, zrf); // рисуем сам куб с текущими углами поворота

        // обновляем экран

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_Quit(); // завершаем работу SDL и выходим
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, не подключены какие-то статические библиотеки в линковщике (файлы .lib, если на Windows).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: А еще immediate mode в opengl совсем устарел.

Comment: Я смотрел уже этот вопрос, проверил на все что там говорится, не помогло. Просто такое чувство что не хватает какой-то либы, но все что было скачено из (https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) подключил,  разрядность библиотеки проверял, тоже правильная x64.

Comment: конечно не хватает, ведь у вас помимо sdl еще куча всего используется