# undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь загрузить библиотеку

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if(WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0){
        std::cout <<"Hello World!" <<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но выдает ошибку

```
undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
```

как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: А какой компилятор используете?

Comment: VC++2019 съедает "на ура".

Comment: Может помочь ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384803/3240681), но можно и в общем случае закрыть [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: судя по сигнатуре у тебя вместо винапи функции вызывается с++, т.к. есть декоратор в имени. возможно где-то она переопределена с неправильным спецификатором вызова(либо макрос не задан). добавь первым #include <Windows.h>, директиву pragma размести ниже инклудов. для теста.