# Запуск Lua файла через C++

Tags: c++, lua, visual-studio-2019

Использую Visual Studio 2019, C/C++, скомпилированный Lua.

Следую данному руководству: https://rubenlaguna.com/post/2012-11-26-first-steps-in-lua-c++-integration/.

Создал папку, положил в неё скомпилированный Lua и сам Lua скрипт. Создал новый проект C++, вставил в него код, указал путь к файлам скомпилированного Lua (include и на уровень ниже) через: "Выбрать проект>Нажатие правой кнопки мыши>Свойства>C/C++>Общее>Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов". Запускаю код, выдает 13 ошибок "Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (main.obj)". Пробовал решить проблему, следуя этим решениям: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B). Видимого результата не было.

Вопрос. Все ли я сделал правильно, следуя данному руководству? Опыта работы с Visual Studio у меня нет, так что я сомневаюсь в правильности своих действий. Сомнения падают на "Makefile" и указании пути к lua скрипту.

Comment: Добавьте информацию из окна вывода. Не из окна а ошибками, а именно из окна вывода. Если там пусто, нажмите пкм по проекту -> пересобрать. Все что там будет написано приложите к вопросу, это поможет узнать в чем проблема.

Comment: "скомпилированный Lua" - что? Вы интерпретатор имеете ввиду? Что касается вопроса: минимальный воспроизводимый пример приветствуется

Comment: Что-то как-то сложно, все на английском, make какие то, я могу показать как это делается, пиши в дискорд sti#7866