# Неопределённая ссылка на функцию шаблона класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему возникает ошибка компиляции `неопределённая ссылка` при реализации в `.cpp` файле шаблонного кода, объявленного в `.h` файле?

Например, есть три файла:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "TestClass.h"

int main() {

    TestClass<char> testClass;
    testClass.v();
}
```

**TestClass.h**

```cpp
#ifndef FILTER_TESTCLASS_H
#define FILTER_TESTCLASS_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class TestClass {

public:

    void v();
};


#endif //FILTER_TESTCLASS_H
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```cpp
#include "TestClass.h"

template <typename T>
void TestClass<T>::v() {
    std::cout << "abc\n";
}
```

Компилятор говорит: `неопределённая ссылка на «TestClass<char>::v()»`. Почему?

Comment: См. в ответе из дубля - "Неправильная реализация шаблонного кода.

Например, реализация шаблонного кода помещена в *.cpp файл, хотя она должна находиться полностью в подключаемом *.h файле." И когда задаете вопросы, читайте описания меток - метка "шаблон" означает "шаблоны проектирования".

Comment: @Harry серьёзно? А почему существует такое требование? Из-за этого же пропадает смысл разделения кода на .h и .cpp файлы. Вообще, можно было бы дать более развёрнутый ответ, потому что в том ответе этой теме уделены две строчки.

Comment: Чтобы рассказывать более подробно - вопрос должен быть задан иначе. А кратко - поставьте себя на место компилятора. Каждый .cpp компилируется **отдельно**, ничего не зная о других .cpp-файлах. Итак, какую `TestClass<T>::v()` - для какого `T` - вы будете инстанцировать? Еще раз - вы не знаете, что будет написано в `main.cpp`, для того и раздельная компиляция.

Comment: Я добавил разъяснение по вашей ситуации в соответствующем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536547/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо.