# Как вынести из шаблонного класса реализацию функции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не могу понять синтаксис возврата итератора класса с помощью метода класса. Вот небольшой пример:

```
template<typename T>
class Test{
public:
    class Iterator{
        Iterator();
    };
    Iterator Find();
};

template<typename T>
Test::Iterator Test<T>::Find() {
    return Test::Iterator();
}
```

На такую запись компилятор ругается на вынесенную реализацию метода.

```
'Test' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

Как нормально вынести реализацию метода в этом случае?
Так же интересует как вынести объявление класса `Iterator` из класса, который его содержит. Т.е в классе написать только `class Iterator;` а остальное объявление написать вне класса.

Comment: Там `typename Test<T>::Iterator ` должно быть.

Comment: А зачем вам выносить реализацию метода из шаблонного класса? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch смысл тот же, что и для нешаблонного класса. Не смешивать определение класса и определение его функций.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я вас не понимаю: про определение класса я вообще ничего не говорил, лишь про реализацию методов. Что касается "того же смысла что и для нешаблоннго класса", то вам следует вспомнить, что реализацию шаблонных функций и методов вы не можете засунуть в cpp файл - она должна находится в заголовочном файле

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Шаблон можно в cpp, если используется только в cpp, или известны типы, которые нужны. См. ревизию 12 [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536547/176217). Реализацию функций разумно выносить из класса, чтобы проще воспринять сам класс, а не листать весь файл. Как я уже говорил, это имеет смысл для любых классов, и шаблонных в том числе.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если используется только в cpp, то тогда хидер зачем? Что же касается восприятия - да, это может помочь восприятию, если вы не имеете тэгбара (что есть даже для простейших редакторов), но реальная причина вынесения реализации в cpp файлы совершенно другая: ускорение компиляции.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch так это ваши слова, что реализация должна быть в хидере. Не всегда и везде есть удобная IDE под рукой для просмотра кода. Достаточно вспомнить этап ревью в браузере. Про ускорение компиляции не понял. В каком случае? Имеется в виду для шаблонов, конечно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я не говорил, что реализация должна быть в хидере - я говорил что ДЛЯ ШАБЛОНОВ реализация должна быть в хидере - это разные вещи. Что касается ускорения компиляции - да, это объективный факт, вы не вкурсе про это? И я не понял про последнее предложение про шаблоны - это к чему относится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Test{
public:
    class Iterator;
    Iterator Find();
};

template<typename T>
class Test<T>::Iterator{
public:
    Iterator();
};

template<typename T>
typename Test<T>::Iterator Test<T>::Find(){
    return Iterator();
}
```