# Линкер не находит символ __times, который определён в libc

Tags: c++, c, компоновщик, libc

Не думал, что буду здесь когда-либо спрашивать про undefined reference, ибо джуниором себя уже не считаю, но тем не менее придётся. Убедительно прошу не ставить дубликат на [известный здесь вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546), я пытался разобраться и привёл здесь максимум информации.

Начнём с того, что у меня специфическая аппаратная платформа: NMC4. SDK скачан с сайта разработчика и установлен без проблем. При компиляции возникает ошибка линкера:

> nmc-g++ main.o -mnmc4 -fexceptions "D:\lab\NMC\nmpp\lib\libnmpp-nmc4d.a" "D:\lab\NMC\hal\lib\libhal-mc12101.a" -o FixPoint
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Module/NMC-SDK/nmc4-ide/lib/gcc/nmc/4.8.3/../../../../nmc/lib/nmc4/libc.a(lib_a-timesr.o): In function `__times_r':
> (.text.__times_r+0xd): undefined reference to `__times'

Символ `__times` определён в библиотеке `libc.a`. Вывод nm:

```
         U __times_r
lib_a-systimes.o:
         U __times_r
00000000 T _times
lib_a-timesr.o:
         U __times
00000000 T __times_r
```

Библиотека `libc.a` подключается автоматически тулчейном, но при принудительном подключении её в настройках компилятора ситуация не меняется. Надо полагать, что эту библиотеку линкер видит: ведь на остальные символы из этой библиотеки он не ругается.

Библиотека `libc.a` существует только в релизной версии. Попытка смены конфигурации проекта с Debug на Release результатов не дала.

Попытка определения символа __times в своём коде

```
int __times;
```

также результата не дала. Я же правильно понимаю, что без модификаторов доступа символы, объявленные в c-файлах имеют публичное связывание?

Техподдержка пока молчит.

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 9    . 2021  .
 *      Author: Alouette
 */

#include "nmpp.h"
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 64

//Вот эта строка, предложенная Fat-Zer, решает проблему, но использовать её - не лучшая идея
//extern "C" int _times(struct tms *buf) {   return -1; }

int main()
{
//Если закомментировать выделение памяти, то программа компилируется.
//Но запускать тогда нет смысла.
//Видимо, вызов __times спрятался где-то в недрах функции nmppsMalloc_8s.

    nm8s *vec1 = (nm8s*)nmppsMalloc_8s(SIZE);
    nm8s *vec2 = (nm8s*)nmppsMalloc_8s(SIZE);

    nm8s *result = (nm8s*)nmppsMalloc_8s(SIZE);

    nmppsRandUniform_8s(vec1, SIZE);
    nmppsRandUniform_8s(vec2, SIZE);

    nmppsAdd_8s(vec1, vec2, result, SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << nmppsGet_8s(vec1, i) << "+" << nmppsGet_8s(vec2, i) << "=" << nmppsGet_8s(result, i) << std::endl;

    }

    std::cout.flush();

    nmppsFree(vec1);
    nmppsFree(vec2);
    nmppsFree(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"привёл здесь максимум информации"* - ¿а где компилируемый код? ¿Это ваш код? ¿Может сначала надо было взять и собрать какой-либо пример от вендора? А то мало ли, там надо шаманить. *"Техподдержка пока молчит."* - так пятницо вечер.

Comment: согласно выводу `nm`'а `__times` как раз **не** определён (`U`)

Comment: попробуй определить как `extern "C" int _times(struct tms *buf) {
  return -1;
}`... количество подчёркиваний определи по вкусу...

Comment: Как обходной вариант - помогло. Правда мне непонятно, почему неопределён символ `__times`, а при добавлении символа `_times` линкер больше не ругается? Разве символ подчёркивания какой-то особенный? p.s. Сегодня получил встречный вопрос от техподдержки. Как только что-то выясним, отпишусь.

Comment: @maestro, на некоторых странных платформах, как windows или различные железки `_` часто добавляется к именам символов компилятором по умолчанию (см. `-fleading-underscore` для gcc)... учитывая, что в выводе nm'а у тебя это так для всех (по крайней мере приведённых) символов, то логично было предположить, что это как раз такой случай...

Comment: Вообще по проблеме: судя по всему, в тулчейне под капотом у тебя `newlibc`, а он требует самостоятельного определения «[Системных вызовов](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls)» для определённых действий ([неплохой блогпост по теме](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/boostrapping-libc-with-newlib)). В принципе это правильное решение, но другой вопрос, что именно ты там такого делаешь, что потребовало вызова `times` (именно для этого нужно было привести [mcve]: это просто из-за инициализации плюсового рантайма или там что-то более специфичное) и можно ли без этого обойтись...

Comment: Хорошо, почитаю на эту тему. Пример добавил, но он, скорее всего, не поможет: вызов `_times` спрятан где-то в недрах используемых функций.

Comment: нуда, судя по всему, если верить репам на гитхабе, то внутри `nmpps*` они `clock()` вызывают... скорей всего это какой-то код для профайлинга... в релиз он попадать по идее не должен, но почему-то они его оставили... в общем, что с этим делать лучше у них спросить... ЗЫ: на всякий пожарный, дисклеймер: я не знаком с этой архитектурой и не так хорошо знаком с применением newlib на разнообразных архитектурах, так что все мои замечания чисто умозрительные...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ответили представители компании производителя, то, что вызов `malloc` тянет за собой `_times`, действительно ошибка. Для исправления создан [коммит](https://github.com/RC-MODULE/nmpp/commit/ba1ee77a1e94a368dfb804f9de95b7bfa80cb953). Нужно обновить библиотеку NMPP и пересобрать её.