# ошибка линковки makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Почему не пишет, что функция неопределенна? Во всех файлах все заголовочные файлы подключены, функции заданы, проблема в makefile. В чем ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам Makefile

```
bin/prog: build/main.o build/draw.o  lib/libmyTerm.a lib/libmybigChars.a lib/libmyReadkey.a bin
    gcc build/main.o build/draw.o -L./lib -lmyTerm -L./lib -lmybigChars -L./lib -lmyReadkey -lm -o bin/prog


lib/libmyTerm.a: build/myTerm.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmyTerm.a build/myTerm.o

lib/libmyReadkey.a: build/myReadkey.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmyReadkey.a build/myReadkey.o

build/main.o: src/main.c src/func.h src/myTerm.h src/bigChars.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/main.c -o build/main.o 

build/func.o: src/func.c src/func.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/func.c -o build/func.o 

build/myTerm.o: src/myTerm.c src/myTerm.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/myTerm.c -o build/myTerm.o

build/bigChars.o: src/bigChars.c src/bigChars.h src/myTerm.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/bigChars.c -o build/bigChars.o

build/myReadkey.o: src/myReadkey.c src/myReadkey.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/myReadkey.c -o build/myReadkey.o

build/draw.o: src/draw.c src/bigChars.h src/myTerm.h src/func.h src/myReadkey.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/draw.c -o build/draw.o

build: 
    mkdir build

bin:
    mkdir bin

lib:
    mkdir lib

clean: 
    rm -rf bin build lib *.bin

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: возможный дубликат: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/178576) // ну и вообще, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: Что такое, например, `sc_memorySet` и где в исходном коде это определяется? Поищите, скажем, `grep -rn sc_memorySet ./src`

Comment: вы `func.o` **не** создаёте, и **не** прикрепляете при сборке.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы задача `prog` собралась нужно все зависимости объявить как нужные. И добавить её в сборку. Например, у вас нужно добавить сборку `func.o`

Makefile :

```
bin/prog: build/main.o build/draw.o build/func.o \
  lib/libmyTerm.a lib/libmybigChars.a lib/libmyReadkey.a bin 

  gcc build/main.o build/draw.o build/func.o \
    -L./lib -lmyTerm -L./lib -lmybigChars -L./lib -lmyReadkey -lm -o bin/prog
```