# Проблема при попытке создать Объект типа Music в SFML 2.5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml, lib, lnk2019

Подключил заголовочные файлы, в свойствах проекта подключил макрос SFML_STATIC, добавил дополнительные каталоги библиотек (SFML-2.5.1\lib и SFML-2.5.1\bin (пробовал и без последнего, результат тот же)), добавил дополнительный каталог включаемых файлов (SFML-2.5.1\include) и добавил дополнительные зависимости:

- sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
- sfml-window-s-d.lib
- sfml-system-s-d.lib
- opengl32.lib
- freetype.lib
- winmm.lib
- gdi32.lib
- openal32.lib
- flac.lib
- vorbisenc.lib
- vorbisfile.lib
- vorbis.lib
- ogg.lib

Конфигурация решения Debug x64.
Выдаёт следующий вывод:

```
Сборка начата…
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: BS, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl sf::Music::Music(void)" (??0Music@sf@@QEAA@XZ) в функции main.
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual __cdecl sf::Music::~Music(void)" (??1Music@sf@@UEAA@XZ) в функции main.
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: bool __cdecl sf::Music::openFromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?openFromFile@Music@sf@@QEAA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) в функции main.
1>D:\File Storage\University\ИТ\BattleShip\BS\x64\Debug\BS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 3
1>Сборка проекта "BS.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "FUCK!!");
    CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(Color::Green);

    Texture Ship;
    Ship.loadFromFile("Pics/ship.png");
    Sprite sprite(Ship);

    Music music;
    music.openFromFile("Sounds/1.mp3");
    music.play();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }       
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема возникла непосредственно при создании объекта Music, если строки с ним закомментировать, всё работает.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Явно там не все библиотеки sfml перечислены. Еще аудио

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)