# Проблема с созданием простого фабричного метод, C++

Tags: c++, ооп

Изучая ООП попытался реализовать фабричный метод.

Описание: В этом примере Фабричный метод помогает создавать
кросс-платформенные элементы интерфейса, не привязывая основной код программы к конкретным классам
элементов.
Фабричный метод объявлен в классе диалогов. Его подклассы относятся к различным операционным системам. Благодаря фабричному методу, вам не нужно переписывать
логику диалогов под каждую систему. Подклассы могут
наследовать почти весь код из базового диалога, изменяя
типы кнопок и других элементов, из которых базовый код
строит окна графического пользовательского интерфейса.

Моя неудачная попытка реализации:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Button
{
public:
    virtual void render();
    virtual void onClick(string action);
};

class WindowsButton : public Button
{
public:
    void render() override
    {
        cout << "Windows button rendering..." << endl;
    }

    void onClick(string action) override
    {
        cout << "> Windows button onClick event!" << endl;
        cout << action << endl;
    }
};

class HtmlButton : public Button
{
public:
    void render() override
    {
        cout << "Html button rendering..." << endl;
    }

    void onClick(string action) override
    {
        cout << "> Html button onClick event!" << endl;
        cout << action << endl;
    }
};

class Dialog
{

public:
    void render()
    {
        Button okButton = this->createButton();
        okButton.onClick("Close Dialog");
        okButton.render();
    }

    virtual Button createButton();
};

class WindowsDialog : public Dialog
{
public:
    Button createButton() override
    {
        WindowsButton winButton;
        return winButton;
    }
};

class HtmlDialog : public Dialog
{
public:
    Button createButton() override
    {
        HtmlButton htmlButton;
        return htmlButton;
    }
};

int main() {
    int osType = 0; // 0 - Windows, 1 - Web
    Dialog dialog;
    if (osType == 0)
    {
        dialog = WindowsDialog();
    }
    else if (osType == 1)
    {
        dialog = HtmlDialog();
    };

    dialog.render();

}
```

Полученные ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я ошибся?

Comment: Ниже человек дал верный ответ. Я дам подсказку: у вас не определены некоторые методы. Прототипы функций объявлены, а определения нет. Если вы хотите только объявить функцию, то ее нужно сделать чистой виртуальной. Тогда наследник-класс обязан будет ее определить. Но так или иначе определение должно быть.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прочтите про полиморфизм, и на основе полученных знаний сравните свой текущий код с рабочим:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Button
{
public:
    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual void onClick(string action) = 0;
};

class WindowsButton : public Button
{
public:
    void render() override
    {
        cout << "Windows button rendering..." << endl;
    }

    void onClick(string action) override
    {
        cout << "> Windows button onClick event!" << endl;
        cout << action << endl;
    }
};

class HtmlButton : public Button
{
public:
    void render() override
    {
        cout << "Html button rendering..." << endl;
    }

    void onClick(string action) override
    {
        cout << "> Html button onClick event!" << endl;
        cout << action << endl;
    }
};

class Dialog
{

public:
    void render()
    {
        Button* okButton = this->createButton();
        okButton->onClick("Close Dialog");
        okButton->render();
    }

    virtual Button* createButton() = 0;
};

class WindowsDialog : public Dialog
{
public:
    Button* createButton() override
    {
        return new WindowsButton;
    }
};

class HtmlDialog : public Dialog
{
public:
    Button* createButton() override
    {
        return new HtmlButton;
    }
};

int main() {
    int osType = 1; // 0 - Windows, 1 - Web
    Dialog* dialog;
    if (osType == 0)
    {
        dialog = new WindowsDialog();
    }
    else if (osType == 1)
    {
        dialog = new HtmlDialog();
    };

    dialog->render();
}
```