# Ошибка при компиляции стандартного виндоус окна на с++

Tags: c++

Сделал стандартное окно виндоус на с++ выдает 2 ошибки хотя все правильно...

```
`#include<windows.h>

int CALLBACK wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR cmdLine, int cmdshow)
{
    MSG msg{};
    HWND hwnd{};
    WNDCLASSEX wc{sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)};

    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra;
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"APP";
    wc.lpszMenuName = L"Calculatro";
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) ->LRESULT
    {
        switch (uint)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        return 0;


        }
    };

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (hwnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Calculator", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 600, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr); hwnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, cmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg,nullptr,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}`
```

код ошибок Серьезность  Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).    КалькуляторС++  D:\Мои документы\проекты\КалькуляторС++\КалькуляторС++\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)    1

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1  КалькуляторС++  D:\Мои документы\проекты\КалькуляторС++\x64\Debug\КалькуляторС++.exe    1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859842/177993 - ваш случай

Comment: `wWinMain` лол что это?