# При сборке вываливается ошибка: LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ __chkstk. Как её обойти и продолжить сборку?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

При сборке на платформе x64 в Visual Studio 2019 сборщик ругается на неразрешенный внешний символ __chkstk. Причем такой же код на платформе Win32 собирается без ошибок. В первом случае (x64) в компоновщике игнорируются все стандартные библиотеки (/NODEFAULTLIB), а на платформе Win32 - нет.

Ругается на эту строку:

```
LPCWSTR filenames[] = { file };
```

Немного кода main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <restartmanager.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

void RegProcess(const WCHAR* file)
{

    LPCWSTR filenames[] = { file }; // эта строка вызывает заявленную ошибку при сборке x64
    DWORD hSess = 0;
    WCHAR key[50] = SESS_NAME;
    DWORD regresources;

    RmStartSession(&hSess, 0, key);
    regresources = RmRegisterResources(hSess, 1, filenames, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);

    //////////////////
    // много кода
    //////////////////
}
//////////////////
// много кода
//////////////////

void mainThread(LPWSTR fileApp)
{
    RegProcess(fileApp);

    //////////////////
    // много кода
    //////////////////
}

#ifdef _WINDLL
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:DllMainCRTStartup")
BOOL WINAPI DllMainCRTStartup(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
#else
BOOL WINAPI WinMainCRTStartup(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdShow, INT nCmdShow)
#endif
{
#ifdef _WINDLL
    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)mainThread, NULL, 0, NULL));
        break;
    default: break;
    }
    return TRUE;
#else
    mainThread();
    ExitProcess(0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
#endif
}
```

Настройки конфигурации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что какой то библиотеки не хватает. Подскажите как обойти эту ошибку, если действительно с ней сталкивались.

Comment: *"Подозреваю, что какой то библиотеки не хватает."* - "*В первом случае (x64) в компоновщике игнорируются все стандартные библиотеки (/NODEFAULTLIB), а на платформе Win32 - нет."*

Comment: Вы можете подсказать какой не хватает? Я только учусь писать на С++.

Comment: Стандартной библиотеки не хватает, которую вы сам отключили использовав опцию `/NODEFAULTLIB`.

Comment: Да, но если я включаю стандартные библиотеки, тогда вываливается при сборке x64 ошибка: LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ WinMain.

Comment: Ну тогда значит это проблема XY. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: Скорей проблема ХЗ)).. от этого не легче новичкам, ведь нигде невозможно найти даже приблизительное решение подобной ошибки, связанной именно с __chkstk. Перелопачивать же все варианты - это жесть.

Comment: Так суть проблемы XY как раз в том, что проблема у вас не та, которая описана в вопросе, а с WinMain...

Comment: А можно кроме скринов еще и код увидеть, вместе со списком подключенных h-файлов?
UPD: Хотя, если почитать MSDN (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/-win32-chkstk) - то причина ошибки очевидна. А что там с WinMain - без кода уже не сказать

Comment: "*неразрешенный внешний символ WinMain*" — попробуйте собирать **консольное** приложение...

Comment: Ок. Добавил немного кода со списком подключенных h-файлов.