# Как подключить файлы Gstreamer в QtCreator проект?

Tags: qt, c++11, qtcreator, lib, gstreamer

Хотел посмотреть как работают библиотеки Gstremer в QtCreator. Хотел запустить примеры с сайта, но столкнулся с проблемой..

**- Как правильно подключить библиотеки?**

У меня выдает ошибки:

> - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol g_clear_error referenced in function main

Так же подобные для: g_free, g_clear, g_print и тд.

> - LNK1120 6 unresolved externals (что логично, у меня 6 ошибок :) )

Читал подобные вопросы и вроде даже разобрался с хитростями подключения, но ответ на этот вопрос не нашел.

**ДЕТАЛИ:**

QtCreator с компилятором Desktop Qt5.15.2 MSVC 2019  64-bit;

Gstreamer 1.18.1 (с сайта скачал: gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.18.1 и  gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.18.1), взял с одной рабочей open-source проги.

**PRO file:**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += "F:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "F:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0"
INCLUDEPATH += "F:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\glib-2.0"

LIBS += "F:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/lib/gstreamer-1.0.lib"


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <gst/gst.h>


#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;

    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* Create the elements */
    source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

    /* Create the empty pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

    if (!pipeline || !source || !sink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return -1;
    }

    /* Build the pipeline */
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
    if (gst_element_link (source, sink) != TRUE) {
      g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
      gst_object_unref (pipeline);
      return -1;
    }

    /* Modify the source's properties */
    g_object_set (source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

    /* Start playing */
    ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
      g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
      gst_object_unref (pipeline);
      return -1;
    }

    /* Wait until error or EOS */
    bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
    msg =
        gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

    /* Parse message */
    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
          gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
          g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
              GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
          g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n",
              debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
          g_clear_error (&err);
          g_free (debug_info);
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
          break;
        default:
          /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref (msg);
    }

    /* Free resources */
    gst_object_unref (bus);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: @Kotomi. Как и писал, встречал этот вопрос и даже решил с помощью его предыдущие проблемы. Но у меня конкретная ситуация.

Comment: У вас не подключена библиотека glib. Вот вы и получаете эти ошибки.