# Boost beast + OpenSSL

Tags: c++, boost, openssl

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто нибудь пробывал собирать пример из Boost beast синхронного HTTPS клиента ?

[Boost beast sync HTTPS client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/client/sync-ssl/http_client_sync_ssl.cpp)

У меня не компилируется вообще никак и ни с каких сторон. Ошибка неразрешенного внешнего символа. Windows10, VS2019.

Из примера буста я убрал почти все, и оставил только это:

```
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>

int main()
{
   
}
```

И вот эти две строчки кода выдают вот эти ошибки:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertOpenStore в функции capi_open_store.    ConsoleApplication1  C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)  1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertCloseStore в функции capi_find_key. ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore в функции capi_find_cert.   ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertFindCertificateInStore в функции capi_find_cert.    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertDuplicateCertificateContext в функции capi_load_ssl_client_cert.    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext в функции capi_find_key. ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
> __imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty в функции capi_cert_get_fname.    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-e_capi.obj)   1
>
> Ошибка    LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов:
> 7 ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1

Как видно тут нет ошибок подключения либы OpenSSL или Boost`а - они подключились корректно, но почему эти то ошибки возникают ?? :(

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем подсказали, что не хватает включенного файла crypt32.lib.
Это библиотека Windows. Если ее включить, то все работает.