# С++ программа при компиляции выдаёт ошибки LNK2019 и LNK1120

Tags: c++

Я только начал изучать С++ и чуть ли не в каждом коде сталкиваюсь с этими ошибками. Вообще не могу понять, в чём дело.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void prog2() {
    int min, max, s = 0;
    cout << "Введите диапозон чисел" << endl;
    cin >> min;
    cin >> max;
    for (; min <= max; min++) {
        if (min % 2 == 1) {
            s += min;
        }
    }
    cout << s;
}
```

Ошибки:

> ```
> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).    Project1    D:\C++\Project1\Project1\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)  1
> ```

> ```
> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
> Ошибка    LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1  Project1    D:\C++\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe  1
> ```

Comment: Так как теперь это дубль, то [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364845/337980) в дубликате будет отвечать на вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ программа (executable) в стандартном случае должна иметь точку входа: то бишь, что нужно делать по ее запуску. По умолчанию, это будет функция `main()`, которой у вас нету.

Если переписать ваш код, просто поместив суть в `main()`:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int min, max, s = 0;
    cout << "Введите диапозон чисел" << endl;
    cin >> min;
    cin >> max;
    for (; min <= max; min++) {
        if (min % 2 == 1) {
            s += min;
        }
    }
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

или добавив `main()` уже вызывающую вашу функцию `prog2()`

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prog2() {
    int min, max, s = 0;
    cout << "Введите диапозон чисел" << endl;
    cin >> min;
    cin >> max;
    for (; min <= max; min++) {
        if (min % 2 == 1) {
            s += min;
        }
    }
    cout << s;
}

int main() {
    
    prog2();

    return 0;
}
```

то вышеописанные проблемы должны исчезнуть. Собственно, первая ошибка:

> ```
> LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main
> ```

вам и пытается на это намекнуть. Просто не очень доходчиво.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Я просто неверно понял роль main. Я думал,что это просто название. Ещё один вопрос есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, какая разница между void и int функциями и что делает return. Просто я понял,что войд ничего не возвращает, но не понял,что значит "что-то вернуть"

Comment: в данном случае, `main` - это функция возвращающая `int`. этот `return 0` вернет `0` операционной системе, что означает, что ошибок по окончании исполнении не возникло.

Comment: когда я вызываю `prog2()` я просто ее вызываю, и так как `prog2()` ничего не возращает никуда, то ничего делать и не нужно. `prog2()` - имеет сигнатуру `void prog2()`.

Comment: если бы `prog2()` имела сигнатуру `bool prog2()` и возвращала по результату какой-то логики `true` или `false`, то в `main()` я бы вызывал ее так: `bool value = prog2()` и мог бы потом, например, написать: `std::cout<<"Function returned "<<value<<"std::endl;`