# Ошибка VSCode C++ Mac M1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, mac, g++

Всем привет. Столкнулся с ошибкой.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"check(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
registration1() in kursovaya-f61047.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Облазил уже все форумы, ничего толкового найти не смог.
Устанавливал все возможные компиляторы(g++, gcc, MinGw)
Курсовую писать надо, а ошибку не могу решить.
Извиняюсь, что без кода, не знаю как вставить сюда красиво его

Comment: попробуйте [установить](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kgtA6vPJOs) codeblocks и в нем скомпилить исходники. судя по ошибке у вас проблема уже не с компилятором, а с линкером.

Comment: codeblocks нет на м1 же?

Comment: народ советует еще  Xcode, CLion, Eclipse. попробуйте поставить что-нибудь из этого на свой мак. многие пишут о проблемах gcc в visual studio code. вероятно, вы неверно установили gcc. если с gcc не получится, попробуйте скомпилить с помощь [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)

Comment: уже с помощью всего компилил(g++, gcc, MinGW) ничего из этого не работает, везде одинаковая ошибка

Comment: добавьте код, просто копируете в текст вопроса, потом выделяете и жмёте на кнопку со скобочками: ```{}```, он отформатируется сам

Comment: Что-то у меня ощущение, что вам надо почитать вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/195342 Ну вот не находит он `check(string,string)`. Может, где-то что-то не так подключили, не так описали...

Comment: А причем тут компилятор?  Компановщик не находит определение функции.

Comment: Думаю, тут проблема в том, что это новомодный мак с арм процессором. И у автора вопроса компилятор и линковшик с библиотеками где то не сходятся