# Как разнести по файлам функцию с++

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с проблемой, как правильно разнести объявление и реализацию фунции между между заголовочным файлом .h и .cpp. Сейчас есть такая структура программы.

.h файл

```
namespace problem {
  class_1 {}
  class_2 {}
  ...
  static std::vector<int> coord;
 
  static void solve(double&x, double&y) {
    //transform coord, use class_1, class_2;
  }

}
```

в .сpр вынесена реализация всех классов. Когда выношу реализацию функции solve в .cpp, то получаю ошибку при вызове функции `problem::solve(x, y)`  (вызов происходит в main.cpp):

```
undefined reference to `problem::solve(double&, double&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Не могу разобраться в чём проблема.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас функция помечена как статическая, это означает (для простых функций, для членов класса и переменных значение этого ключевого слова другое) что она доступна только в пределах той же единицы трансляции, т.е. того же cpp файла, а вы ее вызываете из main.cpp.

При этом когда вы убираете реализацию в .h, при включении этого заголовочного файла в main.cpp, реализация этой функции фактически оказывается в файле main.cpp, то есть в том же файле, что и ее вызов, и ее статичности не мешает вызову.

Чтобы функцию можно было вызвать из main, уберите `static`

Comment: благодарю, с этим разобрался. Буду признателен, если поможете разобраться теперь с другим вопросом. `static std::vector<int> coord;` в этот вектор добавляю элементы так же в main.cpp. Дальнейшая обработка вектора идет в `problem::solve(double&x, double&y)`. Как лучше организовать его передачу в функцию? Если убираю `static` в `main.cpp` вознимают ошибки. `multiple definition of  problem::solve`. Заранее прошу прощения за такие ворпосы, только начинаю осваивать с++

Comment: Я не уверен, что правильно понял, в чем именно проблема. Но если у вас `coord` это данные, необходимые для расчета в функции `solve`, я бы с точки зрения дизайна предложил передавать их в функцию `solve` как параметр, а заполнять видимо в `main`. А вообще лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, там опишите, какая структура у вас получается сейчас, посмотрим