# Почему возникает ошибка "неопределённая ссылка"

Tags: c++

Есть класс GameObject

```
// GameObject.hpp
#pragma once

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "vector"
#include "Core/Window.hpp"
#include "Core/BaseComponents/Component.hpp"


using namespace sf;

namespace sfp::core{
    class Component;
    class Window;
    class GameObject : public RectangleShape{
    public:
        virtual void addComponent(const sfp::core::Component& component);

        template<class T>
        T* findComponentByType();

    protected:
        std::vector<Component*> components;
    };
}
```

```
// GameObject.cpp
#include "Core/GameObject.hpp"

using namespace sfp::core;

void GameObject::addComponent(const sfp::core::Component& component){
    auto* link = (Component *) &component;
    components.push_back(link);
}

template<class T>
T* GameObject::findComponentByType() {
    for (auto component : components) {
        if (auto found = dynamic_cast<T*>(component)) {
            return found;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Также есть дочерний от GameObject класс Button

```
//Button.hpp
#pragma once

#include "Core.hpp"
#include "Ui/Components/ButtonComponent.hpp"
#include "functional"

namespace sfp::ui{
    class Button : public sfp::core::GameObject{
    public:
        explicit Button(const Vector2f& size = Vector2f(0, 0));

        void connect(const std::function<void()>& func);

    };
}
```

```
//Button.cpp
#include "Ui/Button.hpp"

sfp::ui::Button::Button(const Vector2f &size) : GameObject(size) {
    this->addComponent(*new ButtonComponent);
}

void sfp::ui::Button::connect(const std::function<void()>& func) {
    ButtonComponent* myButtonComponent = findComponentByType<ButtonComponent>();
}
```

При попытке компиляции вижу следующее:

```
CMakeFiles/sfml-palm.dir/src/Ui/Button.cpp.o: в функции «sfp::ui::Button::connect(std::function<void ()> const&)»:
/home/navnica/Рабочий стол/sfml-palm/src/Ui/Button.cpp:8: неопределённая ссылка на «sfp::ui::ButtonComponent* sfp::core::GameObject::findComponentByType<sfp::ui::ButtonComponent>()»
```

Сначала думал что GameObject просто не знает что такое ButtonComponent, и потому и ругается. Напрямую подключил ButtonComponent.hpp в GameObject.cpp, но эффект остался тот-же

Comment: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/3380)

Comment: В button.cpp недоступно определение `findComponentByType()`, вот она и не инстанцируется.

Comment: @Harry почему оно недоступно? Ведь класс наследуется от GameObject, и должен перенимать все публичные поля? Я не совсем понимаю как это работает просто

Comment: Потому что *объявление* доступно, так что он компилирует... А тело - нет: оно только в GameObject.cpp есть. А в GameObject.cpp компилятору неизвестно, для чего вы его там инстанцировать собрались... Словом, пока всерьез не разберетесь — пользуйтесь правилом "шаблоны — только в заголовочных файлах" :)