# Как исправить ошибку undefined reference to glu*?

Tags: opengl, glut

Я пытаюсь разобраться с opengl и у меня не получается нарисовать цилиндр.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <glew.h>
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <glut.h>
 #include <freeglut.h>



 using namespace std;
 int main() {
 int result = glfwInit();
 if(result == -1){
     return 1;
 }
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "001", NULL, NULL);
if(window == NULL){
    return 1;
}

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    GLUquadricObj *qua;
    qua = gluNewQuadric();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glRotatef(0.05, 0.2, 0.8, 0);
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-1.5f); // Центр цилиндра
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(qua, GLU_LINE);
    gluCylinder(qua,1.0f,1.0f,3.0f,32,32);
    glVertex3d(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    int angle;
    float r = 0.8;
    for (angle = 0; angle <= 365; angle += 1){
        double x = r * cos(angle * 3.14 / 180);
        double y = r * sin(angle * 3.14 / 180);
        glVertex3d(x + 0.0f,0.0f, y + 0.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\jb\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -g  CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj -o untitled.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libuntitled.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LD:/libs/glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64   -LD:/libs/glut/lib/x64   -LD:/libs/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/x64 -lglfw3  -lgdi32  -lopengl32  -lglew32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj:D:/libs/glut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:637: undefined reference to `__imp___glutInitWithExit'
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj:D:/libs/glut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:639: undefined reference to `__imp___glutCreateWindowWithExit'
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj:D:/libs/glut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:641: undefined reference to `__imp___glutCreateMenuWithExit'
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj:D:/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric'
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
D:/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `gluQuadricDrawStyle'
D:\jb\CLion 2022.2.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `gluCylinder'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)