# Сломалась кросс-компиляция при переходе с ubuntu20 на ubuntu22.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, кросс-компиляция

Вниманию, тех, кто закрыл вопрос! Прочитайте внимаетльно вопрос, суть его не имеет ничего общего с [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)
Там идет речь о том, как избежать неразрешенный внешний символ В СВОЕМ КОДЕ. Здесь речь идет о технической проблеме при переустановкой ОС!

---

Прекрасно работала кросскомпиляция через `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` (были настоенны Kits в QT Creator на специально скомпилированной версии Qt 5.12.3 под наш дивайс) в среде Ubuntu 20.04. Чёрт дернул проабгрейдить до 22.04 и это привело к сабжу.

Sysroot здесь: `/home/asianirish/img/armbian`
(содержимое библиотек сисрута одно и тоже, тогда и сейчас)

Компилятор из пакета g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf: `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`

Вот, что насыпало:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '_dl_make_stack_executable@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_dlclose@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__libc_dlopen_mode@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_longjmp@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_dl_error_tsd@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_vfork@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_allocate_rtsig_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_getres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_thread_freeres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_getcpuclockid@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_addr@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_pthread_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_current_sigrtmin_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_sym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__libc_dlsym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_current_sigrtmax_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_vsym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_settime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

С чего бы появились undefined referenceы там, где раньше все работало???
Что делать? Остатков ума не приложу!

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что текущий вопрос не имеет НИЧЕГО общего с упомянутым? Сборка чего-то стороннего — это всё равно сборка. И указанные варианты из предложенного дубликата вполне имеют место быть. В данном случае, вероятно, проблема в разных версиях библиотек. Я бы предложил развернуть систему с чистого листа в виртуалке и проверить работоспособность. Если всё будет нормально, сравнить версии используемых библиотек.