# Golang и C неопределённая ссылка на метод

Tags: c, golang

При попытке использовать си библиотеку в golang получаю ошибку

```
/snap/go/10390/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-3586512975/000001.o: в функции 
«_cgo_b7334996796a_Cfunc_Register_Card»:
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:55: неопределённая ссылка на «Register_Card»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Вот пример кода на go:

```
package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -Wall -O2 -m64 -I/usr/local/adlink/pcis-dask/include64
//#include "dask.h"
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var card C.I16 = 1
    var cardNumber C.U16 = 0

    card = C.Register_Card(C.PCI_7432, cardNumber)
    fmt.Printf("open device file successfully!! %v \n", card)
}
```

Компилирую `go build main.go`

PS код на си с той же библиотекой и теми же параметрами запускается, всё ок.

Информации в сети по конкретно этой библиотеке нет, это софт для довольно редкой промышленной платки. И опыта работы с CGO тоже мало, поэтому прошу помощи сообщества

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: Вероятнее всего ответ таится в LDFLAGS и особенностях подключения с в go. Природа неопределенных ссылок известна.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, необходимо добавить ссылки на директорию библиотеки и ссылку -l

```
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/adlink/lib64 -lpci_dask64
```

Всё скомпилировалось, надеюсь кому то пригодится.