# Делаю шифратор на основе переменного сдвига символов по ключу, возникают ошибки [ilink 32 Error]

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder

*Программирую в Embarcadero C++ Builder 11*

Dll компилируется спокойно, а вот при компиляции самой программы возникают ошибки:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Encrypt' referenced from D:\TTT\WIN32\DEBUG\PROGRAMMA.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Decrypt' referenced from D:\TTT\WIN32\DEBUG\PROGRAMMA.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

Ошибка где-то кроется судя по всему в programma но только в чем именно уже 3 дня понять не могу.

programma.cpp

```
c++//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "parol.h"
#include "dllL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "programma.h"
#include "about.h"
#include "parolchange.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <System.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
// Объявления функций
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) UnicodeString __stdcall Encrypt(const UnicodeString &text, int key);
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) UnicodeString __stdcall Decrypt(const UnicodeString &encryptedText, int key);
TForm2* Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner) {}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::N1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    Form3->ShowModal();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Открытие незашифрованного файла через кнопку
void __fastcall TForm2::Button3Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = OpenDialog1->FileName;
        Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Сохранение незашифрованного файла через кнопку
void __fastcall TForm2::Button4Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (text != "")
        Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile(text);
    else if (SaveDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = SaveDialog1->FileName;
        Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile(SaveDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Открытие зашифрованного файла через кнопку
void __fastcall TForm2::Button6Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = OpenDialog1->FileName;
        Memo2->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Сохранение зашифрованного файла через кнопку
void __fastcall TForm2::Button5Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (text != "")
        Memo2->Lines->SaveToFile(text);
    else if (SaveDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = SaveDialog1->FileName;
        Memo2->Lines->SaveToFile(SaveDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Открытие незашифрованного файла через меню
void __fastcall TForm2::N10Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = OpenDialog1->FileName;
        Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Сохранение незашифрованного файла через меню
void __fastcall TForm2::N11Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (text != "")
        Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile(text);
    else if (SaveDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = SaveDialog1->FileName;
        Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile(SaveDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Открытие зашифрованного файла через меню
void __fastcall TForm2::N12Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = OpenDialog1->FileName;
        Memo2->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Сохранение зашифрованного файла через меню
void __fastcall TForm2::N13Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    UnicodeString text = "";
    if (text != "")
        Memo2->Lines->SaveToFile(text);
    else if (SaveDialog1->Execute()) {
        text = SaveDialog1->FileName;
        Memo2->Lines->SaveToFile(SaveDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Вызов окна смены пароля
void __fastcall TForm2::N7Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    Form4->Show();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Вызов окна О программе
void __fastcall TForm2::N9Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    Form3->ShowModal();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Завершение работы программы, закрытие главного окна
void __fastcall TForm2::N5Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    Form1->Close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"dllL.dll"); // Загрузка DLL-библиотеки
    if (hDll)
    {
        // Получение значения ключа из компонента TEdit
        int key = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);

        // Шифрование текста из Memo1 и вывод результата в Memo2
        UnicodeString encryptedText = Encrypt(Memo1->Text, key);
        Memo2->Text = encryptedText;
    }
    else
    {
        ShowMessage("Не удалось загрузить библиотеку dllL.dll");
    }

    FreeLibrary(hDll);

    if (Memo1->Lines->Text == "") {
        ShowMessage("Введите незашифрованный файл!");
    }

    if (Edit1->Text == "") {
        ShowMessage("Введите ключ!");
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::Button2Click(TObject* Sender)
{       HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"dllL.dll");
    if (hDLL)
        {
            /// Получение значения ключа из компонента TEdit
        int key = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);

        // Расшифровка текста из Memo2 и вывод результата в Memo1
        UnicodeString decryptedText = Decrypt(Memo2->Text, key);
        Memo1->Text = decryptedText;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage("Не удалось загрузить библиотеку dllL.dll");
        }

        FreeLibrary(hDLL);

    if (Memo2->Lines->Text == "") {
        ShowMessage("Введите незашифрованый файл!");
    }
    if (Edit1->Text == "") {
        ShowMessage("Введите ключ!");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

programma.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef programmaH
#define programmaH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Dialogs.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Menus.hpp>
#include <System.hpp>
#include "dllL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "programma.h"
#include "about.h"
#include "parolchange.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <System.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    TButton *Button3;
    TMemo *Memo1;
    TOpenDialog *OpenDialog1;
    TMainMenu *MainMenu1;
    TMemo *Memo2;
    TButton *Button4;
    TButton *Button5;
    TButton *Button6;
    TMenuItem *N1;
    TMenuItem *N2;
    TMenuItem *N3;
    TMenuItem *N4;
    TMenuItem *N5;
    TMenuItem *N6;
    TMenuItem *N7;
    TMenuItem *N8;
    TMenuItem *N9;
    TSaveDialog *SaveDialog1;
    TMenuItem *N10;
    TMenuItem *N11;
    TMenuItem *N12;
    TMenuItem *N13;
    TLabel *Label1;
    TLabel *Label2;
    TLabel *Label4;
    TEdit *Edit1;
    void __fastcall N1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button3Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button6Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N10Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N12Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N11Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N13Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N5Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button5Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button4Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N7Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N9Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
private:
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm2 *Form2;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UnicodeString __stdcall Encrypt(const UnicodeString &text, int key);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UnicodeString __stdcall Decrypt(const UnicodeString &encryptedText, int key);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

dllL.cpp

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && defined(__clang__) && defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_WIN64)
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include "dllL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <System.hpp>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UnicodeString __stdcall Encrypt(const UnicodeString &text, int key);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UnicodeString __stdcall Decrypt(const UnicodeString &encryptedText, int key);


UnicodeString __stdcall Encrypt(const UnicodeString &text, int key) {
    UnicodeString result;
    for (int i = 1; i <= text.Length(); ++i) {
        wchar_t ch = text[i];
        wchar_t newChar = ch + (key + i) % 256;
        result += newChar;
    }
    return result;
}

UnicodeString __stdcall Decrypt(const UnicodeString &encryptedText, int key) {
    UnicodeString result;
    for (int i = 1; i <= encryptedText.Length(); ++i) {
        wchar_t ch = encryptedText[i];
        wchar_t newChar = ch - (key + i) % 256;
        result += newChar;
    }
    return result;
}
#endif
```

dllL.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)