# C++ как сделать ожидание завершения процесса

Tags: c++, windows

Моя цель сделать так, чтобы программа начинала выполнять дальнейший код только после того, как cmd.exe выполнит команду и умрёт. Так, чтобы после смерти процесса cmd.exe программа начинала выполнять команду `cout << "test" << endl;`

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/C pause", 0, SW_SHOW);
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

Когда я компилирую пример от [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670)

У меня вылетает компилятор с ошибкой:
`if ($?) { g++ writer.cpp -o writer } ; if ($?) { .\writer } D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mattc\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7ezUqJ.o:writer.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to '__imp_CoInitializeEx' D:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mattc\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7ezUqJ.o:writer.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to '__imp_CoUninitialize' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h> int system(const char *command);`

Comment: спасибо, но мне надо чтобы команда срабатывала в новой консоли, а не в консоли проекта

Comment: Используйте фунуцию `ShellExecuteEx` + `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: `ShellExecuteEx` заполняет дескриптор созданного процесса

Comment: `ShellExecuteEx` а не `ShellExecuteW`.

Comment: Программа вылетает

Comment: Передавайте дескриптор **процесса**, а не окна.

Comment: передал `cnsl.hProcess`, но ожидание то не работает, то работает, то вылетает, как это пофиксить?

Comment: структуру `SHELLEXECUTEINFO ` необходимо инициализировать нулями перед заполнением перед отправкой в функцию, а у вас в половине полей мусор. Еще перед использованием `ShellExecuteEx` необходимо выполнять `CoInitializeEx`. А результаты вызовов - проверять. Поле `lpFile` обычно только для имени исполняемого файла, а аргументы следует в поле параметров пихать.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я так и не смог завершить проект на C++, но я сделал точно такой же проект на Rust. Rust более легче и эффективнее в этом плане, т. к. получилось все коротко и сам раст быстрее, чем C++.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле так делать нельзя.
В данном случае, ты выполняешь запуск через Shell, не имея хендла на процесс.

Ты, конечно, можешь сделать что-то типо фиксации процесса через проверку запущен ли ещё этот процесс, но если ты будешь проверять cmd.exe, то в системе таких процессов может быть несколько. В таком случае алгоритм будет не полноценным.

Для нормальной работы тебе нужно использовать WinAPI.
А именно - CreateProcess.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes

Comment: Так `ShellExecuteW` это тоже winapi. Судя по комментам, из `ShellExecuteEx` можно достать handle.

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования `ShellExecuteExW` с `WaitForSingleObject`:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    if (not SUCCEEDED(::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED bitor COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)))
    {
        ::std::cerr << "CoInitializeEx failed" << ::std::endl;
        ::std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFOW info
        {
            .cbSize{sizeof(info)}
        ,   .fMask{SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS}
        ,   .lpVerb{L"open"}
        ,   .lpFile{L"cmd.exe"}
        ,   .lpParameters{L"/C pause"}
        ,   .nShow{SW_SHOW}
        };
        if ((FALSE == ::ShellExecuteExW(::std::addressof(info))) or (not info.hProcess))
        {
            ::std::cerr << "ShellExecuteExW failed" << ::std::endl;
            ::std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != ::WaitForSingleObject(info.hProcess, INFINITE))
        {
            ::std::cerr << "WaitForSingleObject failed" << ::std::endl;
            ::std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ::CloseHandle(info.hProcess);
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    ::std::cout << "done" << ::std::endl;
    ::std::system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: у меня вылетает компилятор

Comment: @adisteyf https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546

Comment: я прочитал, но ничем не помогло

Comment: @adisteyf Ну так надо еще понять и сделать то, что написано в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить решение с использованием библиотеки cstdlib:

```
#inclide <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cd /d C:/Windows/System32 && cmd.exe");
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

Запускается командная строка с правами администратора, код самой программы не выполняется до закрытия командной строки командой "exit".